A more general version of Folland, "Real Analysis", Theorem 1.14
Let $ X $ be a set. Let $ \mathcal E $ be a semi-ring of ("elementary") subsets of $ X $, i.e. assume that

$ \emptyset\in \mathcal E $;
$ \mathcal E $ is closed for finite intersections;
the set difference $ F\setminus E $ between two members of $ \mathcal E $ can always be written as a finite union of disjoint members of $ \mathcal E $.

Let $ \rho\colon \mathcal E\to \left[0,+\infty\right] $ be a set function satisfying the following properties:

$ \rho(\emptyset) = 0 $
$ \rho $ is additive, i.e., $ \rho\Bigl(\bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j\Bigr) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb N}\rho(E_j) $ whenever $ \{E_j\} $ is a countable collection of disjoint members of $ \mathcal E $ and $\bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j\in\mathcal{E}$;
$ \rho $ is $ \sigma $-subadditive, i.e., $ \rho(E)\leqq \sum_{j\in \mathbb N}\rho(E_j) $ whenever $ E\in \mathcal E $ and $ \{E_j\} $ is a countable collection of (not necessarily disjoint) members of $ \mathcal E $ such that $ E\subset \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N}E_j $.

Assume moreover that the entire space $ X $ can be covered by a countable family $ \{E_j\} $ of members of $ \mathcal E $ such that $ \rho(E_j) < +\infty $.
I'm trying to show that every measure on the $ \sigma $-algebra $ \langle \mathcal E\rangle_\sigma $ generated by $ \mathcal E $ that extends $ \rho $ is uniquely determined by the values it assumes on the members of $ \mathcal E $.
Folland's Real Analysis provide a cute proof of this fact but assumes stronger hypotheses[*], and it's argument can't directly be carried over to the present setting. I was wondering if it would be possible to find an elementary proof this fact along the lines of the one that appears in Folland's book without appealing to big theorems like $ \pi $-$ \lambda $'s or whatever.
[*] I.e., he assumes that $ \mathcal E $ is an algebra of subsets of $ X $ and $ \rho $ is a premeasure on $ X $. It can be shown that under these requirements $ \rho $ satisfy properties 1., 2. and 3.
EDIT: The question has been marked as duplicate of this other question. While that question address the existence issue, it does not provide a satisfactory answer about uniqueness. I'm sure that one can prove that $ \mu $ is unique even in my setting.

I glanced at the book (I'll take a closer look later) and it seems that he doesn't consider the issue of uniqueness.

Your assumption (2) for $\rho$ is not quite correct. You also need that $F:=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}E_j\in\mathcal{E}$ otherwise $\rho(F)$ does not makes sense (starting with the assumption that $\rho$ is a premeasure defined on $\mathcal{E}$.

For semi rings the uniqueness is not guaranteed. Here is a simple example of this.
Suppose $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$,  $\mathcal{R}=\{\emptyset,\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\}\}$, and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, $\mu(\{2,4,6\})=\frac12=\mu(\{1,3,5\}). $ $\mathcal{R}$ is a semiring and generates the $\sigma$-algebra
$\sigma(\mathcal{R})=\{\emptyset,\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{1,3,5,7\},\{2,4,6,7\},\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},\{7\},\Omega\}$.
The function $\mu$  is of course additive and countably subadditive on $\mathcal{R}$. The extension $\mu'$ of $\mu$ using Caratheodory's construction gives $\mu'(A)=\infty$ for any set $A\in\sigma(\mathcal{R})$ that contains $7$.
There are infinite extensions of $\mu$ that yield a measure on $(\Omega,\sigma(\mathcal{R})$. Indeed letting $\mu_q(\{7\})=q$ for some $q\in[0,\infty]$ we obtain an uncountable set of extensions for $\mu$. For each $q$, $\mu_q(\Omega)=1+q$.
The extension $\mu_0$ of $\mu$ that assigned $\nu(\{7\})=0$ yields a probability measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$.
The measure provided by Charatheodory is unique in the sense that is maximal:

Any extension $\nu$ of $\rho$ from $\mathcal{R}$ to $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$ satisfies $\nu\leq \rho'$ on $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$ where $\rho'$ is Caratheodory's extension.

Notice that in the example presented above, Caratheodory's extension measure $\mu'$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Rermarks:

When (a) $\mathcal{E}$ is a ring ($\mathcal{E}$ is a smearing closed under relative differences, i.e., $E,F\in\mathcal{E}$ implies $E\setminus F\in\mathcal{E}$) or (b)  $\mathcal{E}$ is a semiring such that the whole space $\Omega$ is the countable union of disjoint sets in $\mathcal{E}$ and $\rho$ is finite on $\mathcal{E}$,  then uniqueness holds. In case (b), uniqueness follows from Dynkin-Sierpinski's $\lambda$-theorem since $\mathcal{E}$ is a closed under finite intersections (a $\pi$-system).
In any event, the extension obtained by Caratheodory's construction has the characteristic of being maximal (see here for details).

There is a smaller structure than semiring that admits a Caratheodory extension including uniqueness under $\sigma$-finiteness as described in (b). This structure is called quasi-semiring. Here is a paper on this.



I thought that assuming $ \rho $ to be $ \sigma $-finite was sufficient for its extension to be unique even in the semi-ring setting. Good to know. What really confuses me at this point is that given a measure space $ (X,\mathcal M,\mu) $ where $ \mathcal M $ is generated by a $ \pi $-system (!) $ \mathcal E $, then if there are $ E_j\in \mathcal E $ such that $ X = \bigcup_jE_j $ and $ \mu(E_j) < +\infty $ then $ \mu $ is uniquely determined by its values on the $ E_j $. This is shown in Klenke's book on Probability Theory. How is this last fact consistent with your counterexample?

I mean, Klenke (Probability Theory, third edition, Theorem 1.53) claims that under the semi-ring and $ \sigma $-finiteness hypotheses the extension $ \mu $ is unique. Examining the proof there's a direct appeal to the fact I reported in the comment above, so it might be that the proof (and the statement) of that fact as written in Klenke's book is wrong (I haven't checked; I glanced at it and it seems that it that uses the $ \pi $-lambda theorem in some clever way).

@GeometriaDifferenziale: As you can see from my example uniqueness does not hold in general. Once you add more structure (ring or sigma finiteness)then uniqueness holds. The important thing is that the Caratheodory extension is maximal, the same way that the Daniell mean is maximal.
